# How do I deploy the master branch if no tag is specified using Capistrano?

Tags: capistrano

Here's what I have in my `deploy.rb` but this always deploys a tag. If I don't specify the tag, I want to deploy master.

```
set :branch, "master"

set :branch do
  default_tag = `git tag`.split("\n").last

  tag = Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask "Tag to deploy (make sure to push the tag first): [#{default_tag}] "
  tag = default_tag if tag.empty?
  tag
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course this always deploys a tag because of this line `tag = default_tag if tag.empty?`

If you set `master` to the default tag like below it will deploy master unless you specify a tag.

```
set :branch do
  default_tag = `git tag`.split("\n").last

  tag = Capistrano::CLI.ui.ask "Tag to deploy (make sure to push the tag first): [#{default_tag}] "

  if tag.empty?
    'master'
  else
    tag
  end
end
```

Note this is untested